What is the best Leg Topology for Animating 4 Legged Creature?
I am making a 4 legged creature for a game in Unity ( A French Bulldog Creature)
But I am having trouble in making the leg topology for the animation as well as making it low poly.
In the below image I have circled in blue the leg topology but I need the topology to look more
clean.

Here is another image to help you lot out (You see how the beginning of the legs are, that radial arc topology)


Asking for the “best” anything is subjective and hard to answer, especially hard to answer definitively. Perhaps you can reword your question to describe a specific problem you’d like a solution to?
